# Inserting Image and title in hubtile without flipping

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, wpf-controls, windows-phone-8.1

I want to disable flip animation in HubTile control for windows phone 8 application so that it should show Image with Text only as it shows in tiles in homescreen of any Windows Phone 8.

Disabling flip can be done by setting property `IsFrozen = False;` and I can see image which is occupying all the space over the HubTile. How can I put text below the image and Image must not be auto-stretchable and must not occupy all the space over the Hubtile? Basically, I want to imitate the same look as it is there for default windows phone tiles. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for doing that you are needed to overlap the TextBlock Control on HubTile.

Try This:

```
        <Grid Height="200" Width="200">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="4*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <toolkit:HubTile Source="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" IsFrozen="True" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="200" Width="200"></toolkit:HubTile>
            <TextBlock Text="Sample" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
```